# How to calculate this derivation

Tags: derivatives

I am starting to learn derivations and I found this problem:
[image]

I am really lost with its. Can you tell me how to solve it? I am also confused because this sample don't have brackets. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want brackets? Here they are:$$y=\ln\left(\cos\left(\operatorname{arctg}\left(\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2\right)\right)\right).$$

Comment: Note that you can apply one more named function to this, if you feel like it: $y=\ln\left(\cos\left(\operatorname{arctg}\left(\sinh(x)\right)\right)\right)$

Comment: A small note, but you should probably refer to it as a "derivative", and the act of taking it to be "differentiation". A "derivation" is a generalized version of this (so it's not technically _wrong_ to call it that, but it does imply a different context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$y=\ln\left(\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2\right)\right)\right)=\ln\left(\cos\left(\arctan\left(\sinh x\right)\right)\right)$$ as suggested by @Arthur.

Using the identities that $$\sinh'x=\cosh x$$ $$\arctan'x=\frac1{1+x^2}$$ $$\cos'x=-\sin x$$ $$\ln'x=\frac1x$$ by the Chain Rule we have that $$\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac1{\cos\left(\arctan\left(\sinh x\right)\right)}\cdot-\sin(\arctan\left(\sinh x\right))\cdot\frac1{1+\sinh^2x}\cdot\cosh x\\&=-\tan(\arctan(\sinh x))\cdot\frac{\cosh x}{\cosh^2x}\\&=-\frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x}=\boxed{-\tanh x}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses are assumed from the inside out, so $$y = \ln\left(\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$

Now apply the chain rule from the inside out.

Comment: should you give me also result for review please?

Comment: @DenisStephanov Did the parentheses help? If you've tried the question with the parentheses, please post what you have tried.